# Smoothing a Signal which contain White Noise

Tags: audio, continuous-signals

I'm trying to smooth a signal in order to reduce white noise as a result of changes in amplitude across sequential frames of an audio signal.

I've been investigating using a moving average or boxcar filter to help minimise the issue.  In my investigations it would appear normal implementations of a boxcar filter only smooth the contents of a single frame/buffer of audio.

Can a boxcar filter be implemented in order to smooth the transition across frames as well? or is there a better approach?

Comment: The problem of the frames of an audio signal being processed with different parameters is usually dealt with by *crossfading* between subsequent frames. This seems to be the best way to solve it. First introducing the artifacts and afterwards removing them with a filter seems suboptimal as the filter will not only remove the artifacts but also affect the desired signal. Crossfading is simple: just let the blocks overlap by a certain length (typically in the order of 10 ms) and fade the first one out and the second one in. To do so, e.g., half von-Hann windows can be used. (see also WOLA.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A boxcar filter is a FIR filter, suppose your frame has length N and your boxcar has a length of M, you will have M+N-1 filtered values.There are 2 properties, time invariance and superposition that you can use.

Assume your boxcar has length 5, and examine 2 sequential frames,data is $x$

$$ 
\begin{align}xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&0000  \quad \text{Frame 1 with 4 zeros post appended} \\
                0000&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \quad \text{Frame 2, 4 zeros pre appended} 
\end{align}
$$

If we could time align the 2 frames, and added them together, we would have continuity across the frames.  This is a consequence of superposition.

If we run the boxcar over each frame,including the zeros
$$ 
\begin{align}yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&yyyy \quad \text{Filtered Frame 1 } \\
                yyyy&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy \quad \text{Filtered Frame 2 } 
\end{align}
$$

Adding the 2 time aligned filtered frames, is the same as filtering a gapless buffer.  This is superposion, and time invariance of the filter.